# reformulating a BVP into a system of first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to convert the following bounded value problem

$y'''+3y''+2y'^2-5y^2=1$ with conditions $ y(1)=1, y'(0)=1 $ and $y''(1)=0$

Into a system of first order Initial value problems in order to apply the shooting method from x=1. I know how to apply the shooting method but cannot work out how to change the variables to get a system of first order ODEs.

I was thinking along the lines of

$y_1=y$,
$y_2=y'=y_1'$, $y_3=y_2'=y''$
which gives the system: $$y_3'=1+5y_1^2-2y_2^2-3y_3$$
$$y_2'=y_3$$ $$y_1'=y_2$$
I'm not sure how to procede by apply the boundary conditions.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure it's $y'(0)=1$ and not $y'(1)=1$?

Comment: yes it is $ y'(0)=1 $. I can then solve this by shooting from x=1 with conditions $ y(1)=1 $, $y'(1)=\lambda$,$y''(1)=0$

Comment: I see what you mean. So, what's your question exactly? When introducing the three variables $y_{1,2,3}$, you know how they are defined in terms of $y$ and its derivatives. A condition $y(1)=1$ can therefore be directly reformulated in a condition for $y_1$.